# XML - "element must be declared" error in IntelliJ?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

I have the following .xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ui xmlns="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <define name="title">Welcome to Registiration Page!</define>

</ui>
```

and IntelliJ is warning me that **element ui must be declared**.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with this xml file or is it an IntelliJ issue?

Comment: I've hit the same issue a few minutes ago, maybe there's a problem with the newest Intellij idea update. As a workaround you can avoid the default namespace with <something:ui xmlns:something="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

Comment: Issue still exists as of 2020 April. Try, for example, with the schema https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xsd and for a root element `note` IntelliJ will say `Cannot find the declaration of element 'note'.` With the official sitemap schema https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd and the root element `urlset` IntelliJ will say `Element urlset must be declared`.